# How can I retrieve first n elements from Dictionary<string, int>?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is there a way to retrieve first n elements from a Dictionary in C#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that there's no explicit ordering for a `Dictionary`, so although the following code will return `n` items, there's no guarantee as to how the framework will determine which `n` items to return.

```
using System.Linq;

yourDictionary.Take(n);
```

The above code returns an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>` containing `n` items. You can easily convert this to a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` like so:

```
yourDictionary.Take(n).ToDictionary();
```

Comment: I'm getting following error after using the above method - 

Error 38 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,int>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,int>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) E:\Assignments\Hotel search web application\Tavisca.Budgie\Tavisca.Budgie.Ui\Models\UserDataAccess.cs 1149 24 Tavisca.Budgie.Ui

Comment: Seems like you are trying to put the elements into a new dictonary. You will have to use Enumerable.ToDictonary() to get this done.

Comment: @buntykawale, As Daniel mentioned, the Take method returns an IEnumerable, not a Dictionary. I've updated my answer to show how to convert back to a Dictionary.

Comment: this is crucial from @Chris Schiffhauer below   dictionary.Take(n).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

Answer (score 17):

Dictionaries are not ordered *per se*, you can't rely on the "first" actually meaning that. From MSDN: "For enumeration... The order in which the items are returned is undefined."

You may be able to use an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) depending on your platform version, and it's not a particularly complex thing to create as a custom descendant class of Dictionary.

Answer (score 14):

Oftentimes omitting the cast to dictionary won't work:

```
dictionary = dictionary.Take(n);
```

And neither will a simple case like this:

```
dictionary = dictionary.Take(n).ToDictionary();
```

The surest method is an explicit cast:

```
dictionary = dictionary.Take(n).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: this is probably the best answer, and needs to be voted up

Comment: agreed and voted up

Answer (score 6):

You can't really take the first N elements from a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` because it is not an ordered collection.  So it really has no concept of First, Last, etc ...  But as others have pointed out, if you just want to take N elements regardless of order the LINQ take function works fine

```
var map = GetTheDictionary();
var firstFive = map.Take(5);
```

Answer (score 3):

Could use Linq for example?

```
 var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

 /// Add items to dictionary

 foreach(var item in dictionary.Take(5))
 {
      // Do something with the first 5 pairs in the dictionary
 }
```